# using object propery as static class name during method invokation

Tags: php, class, object, methods, static

suppose I have a static class A with static method b()

now suppose I have class C with class variable functionName = 'A';

so I want to invoke A's b() function in one line via the following:

```
//within class C
$this->functionName::b();
```

however this ends up returning parse error....is there a way that I can invoke A::b() when via $this->functionName when $this->functionName = 'A' in just one line without call_user_func etc?

Comment: Sorry did not read the question properly :(

Comment: Why are you opposed to `call_user_func`? That's the reason it exists (partly). To make dynamic calls like this.

Comment: if $this->functionName were a normal variable eg $x it would work....eg $x::b() would work if $x = 'A'....since $this->functioName is also just a variable just like $x I'm trying to use this same notation

Comment: Then make it a normal (local) variable. `$className = $this->className; $className::b();` works great. Two lines of code. Or use `call_user_func` for one line of code. You have two great options.

Comment: Well that has been possible since 5.3. Which begs the question, what version are you on?

Comment: don't want 2 lines of code. don't want call_user_func. 

@DavidSoussan I'm using 5.5.14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Uniform Variable Syntax RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/uniform_variable_syntax) covers this, and has been implemented for PHP 7.

It has not been back-ported, you will not be able to use that syntax in any version prior.

---

#### PHP 7 Example:

```
class a
{
    static public function b()
    {
        echo "Hello!";
    }
}

class c
{
    public $functionName = 'a';

    public function run()
    {
        $this->functionName::b();
    }
}

(new c)->run();
```

---

#### Output:

```
Hello!
```